# Default access for Opportunity team member

Tags: apex

I has trying to add opportunity team member using apex.

Here is code snipet.

```
OpportunityTeamMember otm = new OpportunityTeamMember (OpportunityId = oppid,UserId = userid,TeamMemberRole = role);
 insert otm;
```

I can see `OpportunityTeamMember`  added to `opportunity` with access level as readonly. how the access level being set as "readonly", do we have any option to set access as readonly for `OpportunityTeamMember`. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Default access level for `Opportunity team member` is `Read-Only` and it is always greater then or equal to the access level of Opportunity.

## **For Older API Versions(before 36.0) following would work:**

Setting the access-level directly throws error that:

> Field is not writable.

So **you need to add the team members to the opportunity and then update the sharing access to the opportunity for these users.**

You can set it like this:

```
OpportunityTeamMember member = new OpportunityTeamMember();  
member.OpportunityId = SomeOpp.Id;  
member.UserId = SomeUser.Id;  
mmember.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Rep';

insert member;

// get all of the team members' sharing records
List<OpportunityShare> shares = [select Id, OpportunityAccessLevel,  
  RowCause from OpportunityShare where OpportunityId IN :SomeSetOfOpptyIds 
  and RowCause = 'Team'];

// set all team members access to read/write
for (OpportunityShare share : shares)  
  share.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';

update shares;
```

See this nice [blog post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/03/17/opportunityaccesslevel-not-writable/) from Jeff Dougles for more information.

## **For API Version 36.0 and Later:**

`OpportunityAccessLevel` field is writable from V36.0. So you can set it directly also.

```
OpportunityTeamMember member = new OpportunityTeamMember();  
member.OpportunityId = SomeOpp.Id;  
member.UserId = SomeUser.Id;  
mmember.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Rep';  
member.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Frodo. This is much helpful.                                                                                                   I have a test class with assert statement where this is checking for Opportunity team number access, earlier this is read/Write, but now this is returning read only, Do we have any new updates in salesforce where default access for opportunity team member changes  to readonly.

Comment: FYI owd for opportunity is private

Comment: @user26702 It seems that if you change Opportunity sharing setting to some other value, the value of OTM's `OpportunityAccessLevel` changes to least possible permission.but it is always equal or greater than the sharing setting of Opportunity.Probably If you want to keep the `OpportunityAccessLevel` value you can create a trigger. Although I have not find any doc which supports this.

Comment: @user26702 You're welcome. If you feel that this answer satisfy your need you can mark it right, if you are expecting more information you can update your question with your exact need.

Comment: We don't have any change in opportunity sharing setting, We are inserting Opportunity team member with a trigger. We have a assert statement in test class which is checking OpportunityAccessLevel is edit, which is working fine earlier but now its returning read only,  Because of this my test class is failing. I need to dig why this is becoming readonly which is Edit earlier, Do we have any updates from salesforce on default access of opportunity team member.   FYI Class version is 28.0

Comment: @user26702 Could you paste your code of test class and may be trigger as well? In your trigger if you are not setting the `OpportunityAccessLevel` field, it would be 'Read Only' by default.

Comment: I can see OpportunityAccessLevel is edit when owd of opportunity is public read/write, and when OWD of opportunity is private/public read only then OpportunityAccessLevel is read only. is this true where opportunity team member default access is based on opportunity access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42259/discussion-between-user26702-and-mr-frodo).